# Cache Folder in PHP 777, Security Concerns

Tags: php, security, file-permissions

I have a cache folder for which I have to set the permissions as 777. I was wondering that anyone could write in that folder and execute a script to delete or hack my website. I am using a completely self-made php script.

How can I cache my website without having any security concerns. The website caches more than 1000 pages a day.

Comment: Only give the user/group access that needs it. World shouldn't be able to write or read. Why not `700`? If this doesn't work, it means that the webserver is configured poorly.

Comment: There's also no reason for this directory to sit within the Web root, unless your server doesn't allow you to do otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two cases,

First case :If you are running PHP on a server like Apache., then you need to give access only to the Apache user, this user depends on your linux distribution, for example on Ubuntu it is "www-data" while on other distros it might be "apache". in this case you should do the following :
first : make sure Apache is owner of the files :

```
chown -R www-data /path/to/cache/folder
```

then give the apache user all the permissions necessary :

```
chmod 755 /path/to/cache/folder
```

Second case : If you run PHP in CGI mode then PHP is the user you need to give access to PHP user itself, just like the above two commands, but replace "www-data" with your php user.